# How do I search GitHub for repos with two files by filename

Tags: github

How do I search GitHub for repos with two files by filename?

I've tried a couple of search synaxes.

## Syntax without AND

> filename:file1.txt filename:file2.txt path:/

The above search only returns file1.txt

## Syntax with AND

> filename:file1.txt AND filename:file2.txt path:/

I get the following error

> **We could not perform this search** 
>   The search contains only logical
>   operators (AND / OR / NOT) without any search terms.

Comment: I think the first one should work fine although it can be slightly inaccurate often. On the example, are you sure you were looking for `.xt` extension and its not a typo. IMO, AND/OR/NOT does not work because its a code search i.e. `filename` filter already starts specifying the particular file where code should be searched. Eg: https://api.github.com/search/code?q=filename:github-dorks.txt+filename:requirements.txt+path:/+repo:techgaun/github-dorks works fine although it has noise too.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR.** This is not currently possible with the GitHub search engine. Although you can bypass the restriction on search terms, you still won't be able to search by filenames in a repository.

---

**How to bypass the restriction on searches?**

> **We could not perform this search** 
>   The search contains only logical operators (AND / OR / NOT) without any search terms.

You can bypass this specific restriction by adding a new term in your predicate:

```
filename:file1.txt AND filename:file2.txt NOT randomtextthatwillnotbefound
```

`NOT randomtextthatwillnotbefound` counts as a search term and you're pretty much assured that it's equivalent to not adding anything (as far as the text doesn't contain `randomtextthatwillnotbefound`).

**Restriction on filename selector.**

Bypassing the previous restriction will not be sufficient however. If you use the `filename` selector you will only have results of type *Code*. You cannot search repositories that way.

In addition, since you'll have results of type *Code*, a search result file cannot be called both `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` and you'll end up with 0 results.

Comment: This isn't working for me.  https://github.com/search?q=filename%3Abuild.psm1+AND+filename%3Aci.psm1+NOT+randomtextthatwillnotbefound  should find `powershell/powershell`